# Any DSLR monitors around 3 inches?

Tags: dslr, monitors

I'm looking for an external DSLR monitor that is not bigger than around 3 inches. For example, 4 or 5 inches is too big. I need something small and not bulky, for skateboarding videography.

Comment: I doubt you will find an external screen no bigger than 3" as that is already the size of the built-in LCD screen of some DSLR's. Some even have 3.2". The main use of external screens is easier focussing and composing, and there a big screen is beneficial. You might be interested in DSLR's with flip out screens (e.g. the Canon 600d) as that will allow you to shoot from the ground, while still seeing the LCD. It's a much bigger investment though.

Comment: have you looked into DLSR controller apps for android and iphone? some of them allow for control and preview via a cable

Answer (score 2):

Zacuto makes an EVF monitor that is 3.2 inches, and I can say from experience this is the real deal...Has built in sharpening monitoring to help with focus support, and has a detachable eyepiece...also look into their camera rigs fro your skateboarding videos, they could be really helpful for you.

http://www.zacuto.com/zfinderevf

[image]